# why cant i display both the colorbar's title and ticks simultaneously?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
gamma=20;
P=0.1;
N=P.*gamma;
lamdazero=1550;
[lamdapump,lamdasignal] = meshgrid(1540:0.1:1580,1520:0.1:1580);
beta3=0.06;
beta4=-2*10^-4;
c=2*pi*3*10^8;
L=1;
A0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdazero);
B0=(1./lamdapump) -(1./lamdasignal);
Third0=10^-9.*beta3.*(c.^3).*A0.*(B0.^2);
Fourth0=10^-12.*beta4.*(1./2).*c.^4.*(A0.^2).*(B0.^2);
Fourorder=(10^-12).*c.^4.*beta4.*(1/12).*(B0).^4;
deltabeta=Third0+Fourth0+Fourorder;
test2 = deltabeta;
test2(~(deltabeta<=0 & deltabeta>=-4*N)) = nan;
[C,h]=contourf(lamdapump,lamdasignal,test2,[-(4*N):N/2:0],'ShowText','off');
caxis([-8 0]);
xlabel('\lambda_p_u_m_p')
ylabel('\lambda_s_i_g_n_a_l')
title('Contour representing linear phase mismatch in terms of pump and signal wavelength ')
colorbar('YTickLabel',{'-4','-3.5','-3','-2.5','-2','-1.5','-1','-0.5','0'})
h2=colorbar;
HandleOfTitle = get(h2,'Title');
set(HandleOfTitle,'String','\Delta \beta (\gamma P_F_W_M)');
```

%If i remove the color yticklabel i get my colorbar title and viceversa
%need to know what to do
%The code works just fine

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of code and increase the amount of text. You could try to eliminate 80% of the code you got with  simple data example, as how the data is computed i irelevant to  your problem! Put a **Minimum** Working Example

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two colorbars, the second overwrites the first.

```
colorbar('YTickLabel',{'-4','-3.5','-3','-2.5','-2','-1.5','-1','-0.5','0'})
```

Creates a colorbar.

```
h2=colorbar;
```

Creates another colorbar and removes the first. Get the handle from the first call and remove the second:

```
h2 = colorbar('YTickLabel',{'-4','-3.5','-3','-2.5','-2','-1.5','-1','-0.5','0'});
```

Then use the handle to set the title as before.